# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at / Accounts has no customer

Tags: python, django

[image: django stacktrace from browser]

The problem arises while creating new users. It says related object does not exist.

`accounts model`

```
class Accounts(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name='date_joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name='last_login', auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # setting username as a key to login. Note: email can also be used in it
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']

store model
class Customer(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(
        Accounts, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,  null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

in your views as the error says you tried

```
customer = request.user.customer
```

while you have nothing namer customer a all in your Customer class but a username

so either :

1. change your query in the views to :

   ```
    customer = request.user.username
   ```

or

2. change the username in your class to customer :

   ```
    customer = models.OneToOneField( Accounts, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, 
    blank=True)
   ```

Comment: I tried '1' using customer = request.user.username but in my views.py i have following code:
order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
            customer=customer, complete=False)
which gives another exception